# Make installation package of C# project

Tags: c#, installation, package

I have done a software in C#. How can I make a Installation Package for the software?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767/what-is-the-best-choice-for-building-windows-installers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767/what-is-the-best-choice-for-building-windows-installers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page), it has been brilliant for me.

If you want to use Visual Studio, [check this link out](http://en.csharp-online.net/Deploying_Windows_Applications%E2%80%94Visual_Studio_Setup_and_Deployment_Project_Types), VS does most of the work for you, but a lot of people don't like this technique.

There is also [WIX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/), which i personally haven't tried but have heard a lot about.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your deployment requirements. Is this using Visual Studio? ClickOnce (Build->Publish) will probably suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Load up VS.NET and create a new Setup Project:

New Project -> Other Project Types -> Setup And Deployment -> Setup Project.

Answer (score 0):

or you can download and use 3rd party installers.

for example install shield